# jstl request performance

Tags: jsf, request, jstl

I have some objects in a list witch are components and I implemented this to show them :

first.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="sceneForm">
   <c:forEach items="#{templateController.model.selectedTemplate.templatesSet.toArray()}" var="templateControls" varStatus="ind">

        <ui:include src="second.xhtml"/>

    </c:forEach>
</h:form>
```

second.xhtml:

```
<c:forEach items="#{templateControls.controlAttributes.toArray()}" var="controlAttributes" >
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{controlAttributes.controlAttributeType.name == 'top'}">
            <ui:param name="top" value="#{controlAttributes.value}px"  />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="#{controlAttributes.controlAttributeType.name == 'left'}">
            <ui:param name="left" value="#{controlAttributes.value}px"  />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="#{controlAttributes.controlAttributeType.name == 'width'}">
            <ui:param name="width" value="#{controlAttributes.value}px"  />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="#{controlAttributes.controlAttributeType.name == 'height'}">
            <ui:param name="height" value="#{controlAttributes.value}"  />
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>

<c:if test="#{templateControls.controlType.type == 'Button'}">
    <div style="top:#{top}; left:#{left}; width:#{width}; height:#{height}px;>
        <div class="gui-component-inner">
            <span>#{value}</span>
            <em class="helper"></em>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

I iterate throught my attributes list and I set some variables and after it I set my component with variables. This works fine but it is not optim. I make a button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Test" actionListener="#{templateController.testAction}" onstart="Utils.PrintTime()" oncomplete="Utils.PrintTime()"/>
```

Witch prints the time on request start and on request end, and it takes 2 second if, if I delete the whole `<c:forEach>` then it takes 0,05 seconds. How could I make a better request time with iteration? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why I get that minus I don`t know...

**Also here is my solution:**

I make an object with top,left,width,height and declared it in the TemplateControl object. On page load I iterate the templateControls.controlAttributes and I set top,left,width,height for each component. And in xhtml I simply write:

```
<c:if test="#{templateControls.controlType.type == 'Button'}">
    <div style="top:#{templateControls.atr.top}; left:#{templateControls.atr.left}; width:#{templateControls.atr.width}; height:#{templateControls.atr.height}px;>
        <div class="gui-component-inner">
            <span>#{value}</span>
            <em class="helper"></em>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Like this I make my iteration in java at the beginning and not in xhtml and I freed from the `<c:forEach>` and `<c:if>` tags and now my requests are very fast.